# Combine data from csv before insert into a custom datatable in wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, datatable

I have a MySQL query that filters all emails from a csv file and combine multiple records before inserting them to a custom datatable in wordpress. This works:

```
$cntSQL = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM {$tablename} WHERE email='".$email."'";
```

but i need a multiple condition like following but this is not working

```
$cntSQL = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM {$tablename} WHERE email='".$email."' AND phone='".$phone."'";
```

I also tried this but not working.

```
$cntSQL = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM {$tablename} WHERE {email='".$email."'} AND {phone='".$phone."'}";
```

Debugging

```
[09-Oct-2020 18:49:07 UTC] WordPress database error  for query INSERT INTO `wp_lubuvna_subscribers` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `phone`, `birthday`, `gender`, `customer_type`, `id_company_number`, `street_address`, `address_line_2`, `city`, `state_area`, `zip`, `customer_from`, `groups`, `last_visit`, `send_sms`, `send_email`, `join_date`, `post_author`) VALUES ('Joshua', 'Hodges', 'guj@wote.bj', '(603) 280-6605', '04/25/1953', 'Male', '499242365', '79808607399', 'Jomuz Street', 'Alser Grove', 'Custipeva', 'MO', '41789', 'tada', 'pacseztoj', '08/20/1988', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', '01/10/1920', 1) made by do_action('wp_ajax_new_subscriber_batch'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, maybe_insert_new_subscriber_batch_database_table
```

the results i am getting from follwoing:

```
$record = $wpdb->get_results($cntSQL, OBJECT);
results:
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 0 ) )
```

Comment: are you getting some error? Please share that with us

Comment: @JitendraYadav Yadav I have edited my question, added some errors i am getting. but those errors i get even when it works.

Comment: The error refers to a different table. Please clarify.

Comment: So you are getting reponse as `count =0` that means there are no records in your database with given inputs. Please check by manual querying database with the given filters and then verify the output.

Comment: @JitendraYadav I have tried following in SQL where all 100 records are already inserted. i get as count=100 `SELECT count(*) as count FROM` `wp_lubuvna_subscribers` `WHERE email=``email` AND phone=`phone``

Comment: @JitendraYadav this is giving 98 records = `$cntSQL = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM {$tablename} WHERE email='".$email."'";` and this is giving me 99 records `$cntSQL = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM {$tablename} WHERE phone='".$phone."'";` just combining the query is not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment you need an `OR` operator not `AND` operator.

```
$cntSQL = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM {$tablename} WHERE email='".$email."' OR phone='".$phone."'";
```